# Java equivalent of Kotlin class with superclass constructor call

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_first){
}
```

I am new to android app development. I was trying to learn how to do a few things and I haven't studying Kotlin yet, how would I turn this small piece of code into the java class?

```
public class FirstFragment {
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Java version of your code:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    public FirstFragment() {
        super(R.layout.fragment_first);
    }

}
```

You inherit from `Fragment` with the `extends` keyboard and then you call the alternate constructor (the one with the layout parameter) from your default constructor.